# How can i create multiple backgroundworkers?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I don't know how many backgroundworkers I will have.
So at top of form1 I added array variable of BackGroundWorker without make instance yet.

```
private BackgroundWorker[] threadArray;
```

Now I have another backgroundworker i start in a button click event and then in it's dowork I just call once a method

```
private void  _FileInformationWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            GetDirectories(BasePath);
        }
```

Then in the progresschanged event I have a foreach.

I want that each time the foreach loop end to make instance for a new backgroundworker to assign to MySubDirectories(DirectoryInfo[]) after the loop the mydirs and convert it to Array.
Then start the new backgroundworker each time with the MysubDirectories or maybe to make a new DirectoryInfo[] variable for each backgroundworker.

There might be a lot of backgroundworkers. But I can't know how many.

Instead doing like i'm doing now

```
if (_FileProcessingWorker.IsBusy == false)
```

Just to create a new backgroundworker after each time the foreach loop end.

```
List<DirectoryInfo> mydirs;
    private void _FileInformationWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
        string[] test = (string[])e.UserState;
        if (test.Length > 0)
        {
            mydirs = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
            foreach (string di in test)
            {
                DirectoryInfo mydir = new DirectoryInfo(di);
                mydirs.Add(mydir);
            }
            if (_FileProcessingWorker.IsBusy == false)
            {
                MySubDirectories = mydirs.ToArray();
                int SubDirectoryCount = MySubDirectories.GetLength(0);
                MyProgressBar.Minimum = 0;
                MyProgressBar.Step = 1;
                MyProgressBar.Maximum = SubDirectoryCount;
                MyProgressBar.Value = MyProgressBar.Minimum;
                _LastCounter = 0;
                _FileProcessingWorker.RunWorkerAsync(MySubDirectories);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your problem only creating unknown number of instances of BackgroundWorker or something else? If so why not just user a List<BackgroundWorker>() ?

Comment: Also, search/google for Tasks and `await`, this is the currently most viable approach for you interest. working with backgroundworkers is kinda obsolete

Comment: I don't think you gain much with this idea.  The hard drive is still going to be the bottle neck, so adding threads on top of threads won't improve things necessarily.

Comment: LarsTech then using the way it is now two backgroundworkers one get directories while the other one make the searching is better ? To stay with this way ? It's working fine.

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't work, but it could be making things slower.  A typical harddrive has only one spindle, but if you have two threads requesting file information from the harddrive, now the spindle has to keep going back and forth between the two locations.  It could be slowing things down.  You are better off just using one thread to do all your harddrive work so that the UI thread isn't blocked.